# Print automatically on form close

Tags: laravel

I have a button that prints something and it works well.

I would like to print automatically when the form is closed.

At the moment the form sends an email to my customers with order details (it works very well) but now I would like to print automatically without requiring the user to push a button.

Please help me. I am a beginner here.

Relevant code:

```html
<a
  href="#!" 
  target="_blank" 
  id="save-and-print" 
  type="submit" 
  title="Speichern & Drucken">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/summernote.js?v=0.72"></script> 

<script>
$( function() {
  $('#save-and-print').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = 'myOrders/replacement/' + '{{ $data->id }}';
  }
});

$.ajax({ 
  type: "PATCH", 
  url: '/myOrders/replacement/' + '{{ $data->id }}', 
  data: $("form").serialize(), 
  dataType: 'json', 
  success: function (data) { 
    window.location.reload(); 
    location.href = '{{ route('print', [$data->id, 'option' => 'advance']) }}';    
  },
  error: function (data) { 
    $('body').pgNotification({ 
      style: 'flip', 
      message: 'Error', 
      position: 'top-right', 
      type: 'danger', 
      timeout: 4000 
    }) 
  }, 
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `print()` in javascript

Comment: I have in it javascript in edit.blade.php and with the buttom it works. How can I do it automatically. I don't want to press the buttom printer. I would like to have it automatically. How I can add print function to controllers after send email.

Comment: You should maybe post the relevant code. Generically speaking, whatever you do on button click, just execute that same piece of JavaScript [on the submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Comment: @Martin Can you post the code off the edit.blade.php and the controller for the edit event?

Comment: `<a href="#!" target="_blank" id="save-and-print" type="submit" title="Speichern & Drucken"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>`

For printer's buttom.

Comment: ` <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/summernote.js?v=0.72"></script>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            'use strict';

            // Save & Print order
            $('#save-and-print').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var url = 'myOrders/replacement/' + '{{ $data->id }}';`

Comment: `$.ajax({
                    type: "PATCH",
                    url: '/myOrders/replacement/' + '{{ $data->id }}',
                    data: $("form").serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location.reload();
                        location.href = '{{ route('print', [$data->id, 'option' => 'advance']) }}';
                    },`

Comment: `error: function (data) {
                        $('body').pgNotification({
                            style: 'flip',
                            message: 'Error',
                            position: 'top-right',
                            type: 'danger',
                            timeout: 4000
                        })
                    }
                });
            });`

Comment: `//Date Pickers
            $('#delivery_date').datepicker({
                language: 'de',
                autoclose: true
            });

            $.fn.exists = function () {
                return this.length > 0;
            };`

Comment: ` var notification = $('body').pgNotification({
                style: 'flip',
                message: '{!! session()->get('flash_message') !!}',
                position: 'top-right',
                type: '{{ session()->get('flash_type') }}',
                timeout: '{{ session()->get('flash_timeout') }}'
            });

            if ($('.notification').exists()) {
                notification.show();
            }
        })(window.jQuery);
    </script>`

Comment: It works with printer buttom. Now I want to have it automatically with close the form, save to db, send email and also print it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same action to take place on the submit event of your form as what happens when your `id="save-and-print"` button is being pressed, you could do something like this:

```js
function printSomething(event) {
    var url = 'myOrders/replacement/' + '{{ $data->id }}';
}

const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', printSomething);
```